# SPFx You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, error, react

I am trying to utilize MUI-X charts in my SPFx web part. The code does not show any errors. But when building or using `gulp serve`, it gives the below error:

```
./node_modules/@react-spring/core/dist/react-spring_core.legacy-esm.js 118:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (118:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| }
| function detachRefs(ctrl, ref) {
>   ctrl.ref?.delete(ctrl);
|   ref?.delete(ctrl);
| }
```

One observation made here is related to tsconfig.js The "target": "es5" causes this issue. It is something to do with chaining.

Comment: Might be a Node version issue. Check that the version of Node you're using is compatible with the version of spfx you're using.

Comment: The webpart was working all fine and good untill @mui/x-charts was installed

Comment: I have the same problem with spfx 1.18.2, nodejs 18.19.1 and react 17.0.1, which all seem to be compatible. The compatibility between spfx node npm and react is listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility. For me it was because of @mui/x-data-grid. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to @mui/x-data-grid@6.19.8 (instead of version 7.1.0) did the trick for me. Maybe the same will apply to @mui/charts